# Use standard array indexing in a malloc-ed solid block of memory

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

I have the following program in C. I use malloc to allocate space for a float array of 2048x2048. I have the pointer to this array and I want to index with array indexes like table[1][2].

I know I could use malloc like this:

```
float ** table;
table = (float **) malloc(2048*sizeof(float*));
for(i=0;i<2048;i++)
    table[i]=(float *) malloc(2048*sizeof(float));
//now table[1][2] works just perfect
```

But I prefer to malloc a solid piece of memory and that's why I used a struct that contains the required table.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ftable
{
    float table[2048][2048];
};

typedef struct ftable ftable;

int main(void)
{
    ftable * A_table;
    A_table = (ftable *)malloc(sizeof(ftable));
    if (!A_table)
    {
        puts("Error allocating memory...");
        exit(1);
    }

    float * A;
    A = (float *)A_table;

    float ** B;
    B = (float **)A_table;

    //I want to access A[1][2]
    //------------   1st way  -------------- works ok
    A[1 * 10 + 2] = 5.0;
    //or
    *(A + 12) = 5.0;

    //------------   2nd way  -------------- doesn't work
    B[1][2] = 5.0;

    //finish
    free(A_table);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I want to index the array this way: A[i][j] and not like A[i*columns + j] because later I'm going to use openmp to optimize some for loops and normal array indexing is required. I'm stuck here and I need your help.

Comment: `float (*B)[10] = (float (*)[10])A_table;`(for update post, 10 --> 2048)

Answer (score 2):

The struct way of doing it is fine, but you have to access the array member:

```
A = malloc(sizeof ftable);

A.table[3][4] = . . .
```

Comment: but I use this code float * A = (float *)A_table; and I use directly the pointer to float

Comment: But you can't do 2D indexing on a simple `float*`. The compiler needs to know the size of the first index.

Comment: yes you are right. Otherwise I will have to do it manually like A[3*2048 + 4] or *(A + 3*2048 + 4). I didn't want to use the struct - BLUEPIXY gave the answer I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you actually do not want to use the struct at all (as suggested in comments), you can write:

```
float (*table)[COLUMNS] = malloc( ROWS * sizeof *table );
```

and then use `table[row][col]` to access each cell.

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) if you are unfamiliar with the `malloc(N * sizeof *p)` pattern.